# Other distributions boot; Debian/Ubuntu based don't

Tags: boot, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi, secure-boot

I need some help on this elusive problem; I hope someone knows how to work around it. I am writing this from Fedora, since no Ubuntu or Debian based distributions are able to boot on this laptop. I just bought a Dell Inspiron 14 5458 with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. Yes, it came with Ubuntu. But it won't accept the ubuntu boot loader anymore.

**FIRMWARE CONFIG:**

UEFI Mode      ON

Secure Boot    OFF

Legacy Support ON

SB Custom Mode OFF

No UEFI entry is created after successfully installing Ubuntu. Recreating the entry and setting it to boot the bootable files I could find in the efi folder doesn't solve it.
However, **Ubuntu does boot if I enable Secure Boot**. But it keeps deleting the firmware boot entry after every reboot, so I have to recreate the entry to be able to run it.

At this point, I'm starting to suspect it's a local problem in the implementation of UEFI/Secure Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points spring to mind:

- Computers that ship with Ubuntu pre-installed often use customized versions of Ubuntu with special (more up-to-date) drivers and/or support software. Thus, it might not be possible to install a stock Ubuntu 14.04 on your laptop, even though it came with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. You may have more luck with a more recent version of Ubuntu, since the support tends to work its way into later releases. I can't promise that, though. You may also have more luck by going to Dell to get media to re-install the original version of the OS.
- "Legacy" mode support entails enabling the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which provides a BIOS compatibility layer atop the native EFI firmware. This complicates the boot path, as described on [this page of mine,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) which in turn can cause confusion and problems. These issues are worst on a dual-boot system; for booting just one OS, using BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting is less of a problem. I don't know whether your original configuration used BIOS-mode or EFI-mode booting. You might need to use whichever mode was used originally; and if that was EFI mode, as a general rule it's best to disable the CSM.
- If Ubuntu boots with Secure Boot active, disabling it should not render Ubuntu unbootable. The only way disabling Secure boot might cause problems is if another (non-Ubuntu) boot loader exists earlier than the Ubuntu entry in the firmware's boot list in NVRAM, and if that boot loader is not properly signed. In this case, with Secure Boot active, the non-Ubuntu boot loader will be skipped; but with Secure Boot disabled, the non-Ubuntu boot loader will run. If that boot loader then crashes, reboots the computer, etc., you'll be looking at symptoms like what you describe.
- Some EFIs are defective and either forget or ignore their boot manager entries in NVRAM. When this happens, booting the system requires copying or moving the boot loader (normally `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`) to the fallback filename (`EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`; both names on the [EFI System Partition [ESP]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)). Follow-on and support files, like `grubx64.efi` and `grub.cfg`, may also need to be moved.
- Sometimes the NVRAM entries work fine for a while but then start failing. In this case, using the firmware setup tool's option to reset all options to the defaults usually works around the problem, although it's also often necessary to re-register the boot loader with the firmware.
- You say you're writing from Fedora. If you've fully installed Fedora on the computer, its GRUB is probably controlling the boot process. Depending on when you tried to install Ubuntu (before or after Fedora) and precisely how you did each installation (BIOS vs. EFI mode, whether you deleted the existing ESP, etc.), you could be looking at Fedora's GRUB setup scripts doing the wrong thing in booting Ubuntu, the two distributions' GRUBs fighting over control of the boot process, or other distribution GRUB incompatibilities. My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) often does a better job of managing a dual-boot of multiple Linux distributions than does GRUB, since it's less reliant on distribution-specific setup scripts and configuration files than is GRUB.

Overall, I suspect that some combination of the preceding issues is the source of your problems, but I can't be more specific because I don't know enough about your configuration or your symptoms. If I were to offer a suggestion at this point, it would be to disable the CSM and try to re-install Ubuntu 16.04.2, 16.10, or even the 17.04 RC (17.04 will be released in two days, on April 13 2017); and when doing so, delete *all* the partitions, including the ESP, to ensure that old boot loaders are deleted. That's pretty generalized advice, though. If you need more help, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborated response. Among the things I tried are: CSM disabled, clean install, fail. Dell doesn't show any link for an installation image for the factory installed Ubuntu. Fedora was installed by itself, after creating a new partition layout (gpt) and letting it use the entire disk. I just want one operating system. One more thing, before I wiped the installation that came with the laptop, I looked at the BIOS settings and I know how it was setup. Secure boot came OFF, CSM came ON. I will try to clean install a newer version of Ubuntu and try renaming the boot files as u said.

Comment: One more important note, I updated the BIOS firmware to a newer version in the first day when I bought the laptop. It's possible to perform a downgrade. I might try that too. Will post any developments here.

Comment: If the computer came with the CSM enabled, then it's entirely possible that Ubuntu was installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode initially, and you might do well to try that approach yourself for your re-installation.

Comment: Ubuntu installed perfectly with UEFI/Secure Boot OFF/CSM OFF. The real problem is that the ubuntu boot entry is sorta volatile. It will boot just fine, but if I plug a Linux USB device to boot from it, it will take over the boot entries and DELETE the "ubuntu" entry. What could it be? Then I try to recreate the entry again and there appears two identical entries (the old one and the one I just created). This is a bug, but why it only happens with Ubuntu installed if it's a UEFI bug?

Comment: That sounds like a firmware bug. There's a new EFI program that's installing now that *might* help. It's poorly documented, but try this: `sudo mkdir -p /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT`, followed by `sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. If my guess about what `fbx64.efi` does is correct, that should work around the problem. This bug may not affect Windows because many EFIs are hard-coded to recognize the Windows boot entry as a fallback option, but not to recognize the Ubuntu boot entry in a similar way.

Comment: I'm installing 17.04 right now. Will report if it works then. Otherwise, will try your suggestion. What is this new EFI program called? I have that fbx64.efi on my /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ along with other one with an unfamiliar name.

Comment: OK, I found documentation of `fbx64.efi` (the boot file formerly known as `fallback.efi`); see [here.](https://github.com/rhinstaller/shim/blob/master/README.fallback) This program is designed to restore missing boot loader entries. It looks like it should normally be in `EFI/BOOT`, but Ubuntu may have changed that to `EFI/ubuntu`. This looks overly-complex to me, but you might try playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I came to the conclusion that the UEFI firmware deletes my boot entries whenever I plug a bootable Linux USB device. Also, there were some glitches in the Setup interface which caused duplicate entries and weird stuff. I have reasons to suspect it's broken.

HOWEVER, this only happens when I have Ubuntu installed.

If I install Fedora, Arch or any other non-ubuntu distro, I can plug USBs and boot the crap out of them. The "fedora" boot entry won't disappear. The "Linux Boot Manager" won't disappear. **But the "ubuntu" boot entry will be erased upon trying to boot a USB device.**

Right now, I don't know what the hell is going on.